# Reading and Writing Devanagri Hindi characters in text file

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, python-unicode, devanagari

Having trouble reading and writing Hindi Devanagari characters in text files using Python.

1. **Reading**: 
   Python is unable to read Devanagari characters in my text file when following code is implemented.

   Code:

   ```
        f=open(r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\abc1.txt","w")
        print(f.read())
        f.close()
   ```

   O/P: à¤® (instead of म)

   While the same code produces correct output for '&' symbols in my file as follows

   O/P: &
2. **Writing**:
    Following implementation throws an error message. 
   Unicode for म being 092e
   Code:

   ```
     f=open(r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\abc1.txt","w")
     f.write(u"\u092e")
     f.close()
   ```

   Error Message:

   ```
    Exception has occurred: UnicodeEncodeError
    'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u092e' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
      File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Python\gg.py", line 2, in <module>
        f.write(u"\u092e")
   ```

While the character writes successfully on standard output as follows:

Code:

```
print(u"\u092e")
```

O/P: म

Kindly explain why so? How can I read and write Devanagari characters on text file? Any alternatives?

[image]

Comment: The encoding used to open a text file is OS-dependent.  specify the *actual* encoding of the file. `encoding='utf8'` is a good choice, but existing files could be in another encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried opening the file with UTF8 or UTF16? It depends on how your source file is saved (which encoding is used).

For example, try:

```py
with open(r'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\abc1.txt','r', encoding='utf-16') as f:
    print(f.read())
```